# Como selecionar um option de um input select com o valor de $_GET com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

A página recebe um valor pelo $_GET e gostaria de auto selecionar o valor de um input select igual ao valor do $_GET recebido com o uso de Jquery:

```
<?php
$valor = $_GET['valor']; // valor1
?>

<select name='selectValores'>
    <option value='valor1'>Valor-1</option>
    <option value='valor2'>Valor-2</option>
    <option value='valor3'>Valor-3</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

});
</script>
```

**RESOLVIDO:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theValue = '<?php echo $_GET['pesquisa-tipo']; ?>';
    $('#formCaminhaoPesquisa #pesquisaTipo option[value=' + theValue + ']').attr('selected',true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer isso direto no PHP? Assim o option já vem selecionado sem a necessidade de usar jQuery.

Comment: Não pois preciso manipular a DOM e não posso alterar o PHP infelizmente rsrsrs

Answer (score -1):

Eu sugiro alternar entre aspas duplas e aspas simples, dessa forma ele vai ler a variável como todo:

```
var theValue = "<?php echo $_GET['pesquisa-tipo']; ?>";
```

Outra solução que eu teria, seria colocar um id no html, para puxar o valor pro javascript

```
<select name='selectValores' id="valores">
<option value='valor1' id="valor1">Valor-1</option>
<option value='valor2' id="valor2">Valor-2</option>
<option value='valor3' id="valor3">Valor-3</option>
```

E no javascript, puxar o valor através de um getElementById